# json.hpp required on linux

Tags: json, linux, cmake

Hi I'm trying to install packet on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but when I use the command cmake ../ I receive the message:

```
-- Poco_VERSION: 1.8.0
-- Poco_INCLUDE_DIRS: 
-- Poco_LIBRARIES: Poco::Foundation;Poco::Util;Poco::XML;Poco::Net
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (message):
  LoRa toolkit requires json.hpp, skipping...


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jayme/LoRa-SDR/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/jayme/LoRa-SDR/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".`
```

I have already installed json.hpp using git clone in this link: https://github.com/nlohmann/json.git but didn't work.

Comment: There is too little information to help you here. Can you specify which packet you want to install? Seeing the CMakeLists.txt from which the error originates would help. Furthermore, the error does not sound as if it makes the build fail. Can you please post the full message? Can you give the exact commands that you entered? We don't know into which folder you git clone'd the json repo.

Comment: I'm trying to install a packet from this git https://github.com/BastilleResearch/gr-lora and I edited the question with the entire mesage

Comment: I don't see any reference from gr-lora to json and cannot reproduce the error message even without having json.hpp "installed". Are you sure that this is the project you are trying to build?

Comment: Is this the project you want to build: https://github.com/myriadrf/LoRa-SDR

Comment: Yes I'm sure this is the one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you try to build https://github.com/myriadrf/LoRa-SDR according to their README.md's instructions and have already successfully installed Pothos, I can reproduce you above error message.

As you already noticed, the problem is that json.hpp cannot be found. Cloning the repository is only the first step to solving this. Assuming you don't want a systemwide installation of json.hpp I would add `include/` of the json project to cmake's search paths by specifying it on the command line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/full/path/to/json/include ../
```

Comment: Tanks it worked but now it's saying that I don't have the file CMakeLists.txt. I tried to change the name of CMakeCach.txt to CMakeLists.txt

Comment: CMakeCache contains vastly different contents than CMakeLists. Renaming won't help you there.

Comment: Yeah it didn't work, but you know any reason for this error?

Comment: No. There is too little information for that. Just as with the original question. You have to detail what you are doing, what the error you are getting is (and maybe what you expected to get). You could add that to your question.

Comment: This is the message I'm receiving:
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/jayme/LoRa-SDR/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Comment: I assume you are running cmake from inside `build/` and forgot to point it to the actual folder that contains `CMakeLists.txt` via `../`.

Comment: I have one more question how do I make a systemwide installation of json.hpp because I think that only using git clone doesnt work

Comment: A systemwide installation would put the contents of `json/include` into `/usr/include`. For many projects it is sufficient to do `make install` (`sudo` is often required for that). Since it is a cmake project you might want to do the following: `git clone ...; cd json; mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make install`